# Is integrated graphics card Radeon HD 4200 capable of handling full HD?

Tags: hdmi, amd-radeon

I enjoy my integrated graphics card Radeon HD 4200 at resolution of 1280x1024 pixels on a 19" inches LG Flatron (5: 4 aspect ratio) (playing FIFA 10 at max resolution, max quality). But recently I decided to upgrade my monitor and to get a 24" inches BENQ, 1920x1080, full HD.

Would I experience any problems with that graphics card on a such a big monitor? Usually I don't play games, just movies/music/and of programming, but it would be nice to be able to play some Counter Strike without artifacts.

**Yes It is. This is the best integrated GPU i've ever seen**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least [according to the manufacturer](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-4000/ati-radeon-hd-4200/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-4200-specificatications.aspx), yes:

- Primary supports 18-, 24-, and 30-bit digital displays at all resolutions up to 1920x1200 (single-link DVI) or 2560x1600 (dual-link DVI)
- Secondary supports 18-, 24-, and 30-bit digital displays at all resolutions up to 1920x1200 (single-link DVI only)

Comment: i'm going to connect the monitor using HDMI cable, and i can't figure out why DVI can handle higher resolution than HDMI? Shouldn't be inverse?

Comment: That I can't answer.

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer? I asked if I would experience problems and you answered `yes`. right?

Comment: Sorry, your question is actually: "Is integrated graphics card Radeon HD 4200 capable to handle full HD?" and to that I said "yes". I doubt you will have problems.

Answer (score 1):

My wife has that card in her computer. While it can do HD (We watch blueray out to a 1080p screen) I don't think it would be too good for most modern games at that resolution. I've gotten Counter Strike Source, though, to run at that resolution with low settings using an AGP GeForce 6800, so in theory you should be fine.

Comment: i was able to play prototype on 1280x1024 but i think i won't do that any more on 1920x1080 :). Honestly, i don't play modern games, just some cs